# Embed HTTP Web Site into SharePoint Online

Tags: html, sharepoint-online

Just wondering is there a way of embedding a HTTP web site into SharePoint Online. I see you can embed some HTTPS web sites into SharePoint Online. I am not interested in HTTPS web sites as such. I have a web page which runs under XAMPP, and I wanted to embed it into SharePoint Online.

Perhaps on the other hand there might be an app that allows such functionality?

Please advise

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you will have is a browser security issue.  If you are connecting to SharePoint online you will be using HTTPS. If you try to iFrame in an HTTP site, the browser will likely block it with a mixed content error.  Nothing to do with SharePoint, this is browser security.

You will need to support HTTPS on your external web site, then use a Page Viewer Web Part to iFrame in your external site and use the HTTPS url.